# JEST typeof function test is always false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

can someone help me out here real quick?
I'm trying to test if a function exists with JEST like this and it always gives me **false** as a result, why is that?
I tried to run the same logic in the formHandler.js and it works there, is something wrong with the way I write it?

```
const { handleSubmit } = '../client/js/formHandler';
import "babel-polyfill";

describe('Testing if function exists' , () => {
    test('Should return true', async () => {
        expect(typeof handleSubmit === "function").toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean to do `require('../client/js/formHandler')`? You're missing a require call to actually import the file. Right now it's a string, which does not have a `handleSubmit` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you could try this:

```
import { handleSubmit } from '../client/js/formHandler';
import "babel-polyfill";

describe('Testing if function exists' , () => {
    test('Should return true', () => {
        expect(typeof handleSubmit).toBe('function');
    });
});
```

Comment: Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-7mmr5?file=/src/components/blabla.test.js). It worked for me (look on components folder)

Comment: Is maybe something wrong with the way I export it?

async function handleSubmit(event) {}

export { handleSubmit };

Comment: Could you take a look here please? https://github.com/stefanfeldner/evaluate-news-nlp

Comment: Yes it's the exporting way the problem. Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-7mmr5?file=/src/components/blabla.test.js) (always in components folder)

Comment: Yes it works but you have to import function in test like `import { handleSubmit  } from "../client/js/formHandler";` Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-7mmr5?file=/src/components/blabla.test.js)

Comment: I tried that, now all test pass, thank you very much Giovanni you saved my day! :)